# Best way to ggplot time series with multiple categorical values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with following data set:

```
team, time, rank1, rank2, rank3, rank4, rank5
bull, 20180102,0,0,0,0,1
corn, 20180102,0,29,0,0,1
fivfo, 20180102,23,4,0,0,1
lazy, 20180102,0,0,0,0,1
tt, 20180102,0,4,222,0,1
cheer, 20180102,23,0,34,0,1
manup, 20180102,0,13,0,0,1
bull, 20180103,0,10,0,10,1
corn, 20180103,0,59,0,0,1
fivfo, 20180103,43,4,0,0,1
lazy, 20180103,0,0,0,0,1
tt, 20180103,0,4,122,0,1
cheer, 20180103,23,0,34,0,11
manup, 20180103,0,13,10,0,11
```

Goal is to plot rank per team while reflecting the date time. I was trying to use melt but can't really figure which axis is to be melt against.

I tried to use the melt as follows:

```
melt.s <- melt(s, id=c("team","time"))
ggplot(melt.s,aes(x=time,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

problem with the above is that `team` name doesn't really appear key take away of the plot that I want to show case is team and the number of time that they have reached the rank.

Trying to figure the best way to plot but so far thinking following

```
 rank5 |
 rank4 |
 rank3 |                    legend (team)
 rank2 |                     
 rank1 |___________________
        time
```

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? It might also help to see at least a sample of your expected output. (I'd think something like `tidyr::gather(dat, k, v, -team, -time)` would be a start for reshaping the data for `ggplot2`.)

Comment: @r2evans just edited the question

Comment: @d.b just added more context

Comment: What do the numbers in `rank1:rank5` represent? Time in that rank? Do they have a relation to the `time` variable?

Comment: @JonSpring How many times a `team` reach that rank on that `time`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
library(tidyr); library(lubridate)
gather(s, rank, rank_count, -c(team, time)) %>%
  mutate(time = ymd(time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, rank_count)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = rank_count), size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d") +
  facet_grid(rank~team)
```

[image]

Comment: The first line with `tidyr::gather` is another way to reshape the data into longer form, akin to `melt`.

Comment: What are my options on getting something like The sketch I did in the question because the data frame i have has 20,000 rows (before melt)